# I am using the program Anylogic to create a stock adn flow model

Tags: java, anylogic

I am using the program Anylogic to create a stock adn flow model.

This is my error...

```
plot.addDataSet(root.InfectiousDS,"CR=" + format(root.ContactRateInfectious));
```

THe error is "plot cannot be resolved". I am not sure why. The instructions were given to me. I did everything to the exactly as it told me. Can anyone help me?

Comment: It means what it say, you are trying to use a variable `plot` that doesn't exist at that point. As to why - we have no idea from the code that you posted, but I doubt you can turn this into a good question for SO (see the [help]). Better to check if you made any spelling errors in variable names, and to go back to the person who gave you the instructions to ask for clarification

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add an actual Plot object that is named "plot". Maybe not explicitly done in the instructions but check for screenshots that show a plot.

Answer (score 0):

Try `chart.addDataSet(root.InfectiousDS,"CR=" + format(root.ContactRateInfectious));`

In some AnyLogic version, new plots started to get `chart` default name instead of `plot`, and it is not reflected in instructions.